# How to add decimal to MS-Access database via EF Core?

Tags: c#, ms-access, entity-framework-core, decimal

We have the essence of `Contracts` with a property `Salary`. Adding to the database using the `Add()` method. Initially `Salary` was `float` type, model and entities were generated by `Jet` provider (it is used for `Access`).

Looking at his other questions, I have repeatedly pointed out that `Salary`, that is `Salary` must be kept in `decimal`. I fixed the type and all related code sections (these are translations from the text and back when the value goes into and out of control).

Field `Salary` in the database were corrected for (in the `Access` via `GUI`) `Cash`, `a Single floating-exact`, `Double exact`, `Valid`. If `Salary` in the code is `decimal` without a fractional part, the addition will be successful. When there is a fractional part, the exception falls:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

When `Salary` is in `float` or `double` code, adding is correct with and without fractional part.

Translation of the text and tried through `decimal.Parse()`, and via `Convert.ToDecimal()`

Hence the question how to add `decimal` to `Access`? By the way, all the mathematics on this field is described by the `SalaryWithTax` property

```
public partial class Contracts
{
    ...
    //public double Salary { get; set; }
    //public float Salary { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    ...
}

static public bool Add(object obj)
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
        {
            context.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... }

    return result;
}

// at the moment all the specified variables in double
public double SalaryWithTax
{
    get { return salaryWithTax; }
    set
    {
        salaryWithTax = value;
        incomeTaxValue = (salaryWithTax * incomeTaxProcent) / 100;
        insuranceTaxValue = (salaryWithTax * insuranceTaxProcent) / 100;
        Salary = salaryWithTax - incomeTaxValue - insuranceTaxValue;
    }
}
```

**Later**

Put the type `Valid` for `Salary` in the database and recreated the model through the provider `Jet`. `Salary` entities `Contracts` got type `decimal`. Added to `OnModelCreating().HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)")`. But it is still an exception when adding a number with a fraction. The debag shows that `Parse()` or `Convert()` make a normal number. `Access 2016`, base `.accdb`

If it makes sense at all, given the limitations of the calculations only property `SalaryWithTax`?

**Update**

I created new data base with `Table` (`int id` and `decimal salary`). Model created by `Jet` provider:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=nameDB.accdb;" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet
```

And `console app` with `Main()`:

```
using(ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
{
    decimal x = 17.45M;
    Table table = new Table();
    table.Id = 1;
    table.Salary = x;
    context.Table.Add(table);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And get the same exception. Write all message:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>
> OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Code `OnConfiguring()` creates a. I tried changing the line. `HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")` with `18, 2` (in database too) - no effect, same exception.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.6-servicing-10079");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("table");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

        entity.Property(e => e.Salary)
            .HasColumnName("salary")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    });
}
```

[Link](https://yadi.sk/d/TerwZw6c6OhPUQ) to download the console program.

**Update**

Or tell me what potential errors can occur if I use `double` in this case

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?  `context.SaveChanges()`? Which class is the `SalaryWithTax` property a member of?

Comment: @AndrewCooper `SaveChanges()`

Comment: If you can do with a maximum of four decimals, try using data type _Currency_ in Access. Decimal as data type in tables is known to be buggy.

Comment: @Gustav I tried. Then `Jet` created `decimal(19, 0)`, but same exception.